# Ubuntu equivilant to windows explorer

Tags: filesystem

What I want to do is edit a file: /usr/share/vlc/http/.hosts. In windows I locate the file click open with notepad.

In ubuntu i go to files/home and i can't see any users.

Can someone point me in the right direction please.

Comment: .hosts is a file name or folder name.

Answer (score 2):

okay now open files then on the left side you'll find option "computer" click it

now navigate to usr > share > vlc > http > and now you need to press **ctrl + h** to show the hidden files (files starting with . are hidden) and open it.